# The URL with parameters in react app does not work in new browser window or tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have react-App with redux using `Asp.netWebApi` as back-end. The site has `tutors.jsx` and `tutorDetails.jsx` components. When the user clicks on the tutors list in `tutors.jsx` component , the `tutorDetails.jsx` component displays.

The link has two parameters in url `tutorId` and `fullName`. like
https://www.virtualcollege.pk/TutorDetails/1105/Sohail%20Anjum
The problem is that when we copy the url and open it in a new browser tab, it does not work.
here is live link for tutors:
[tutors list live link](https://www.virtualcollege.pk/Tutors)
Here is the live link for detail page: [the tutorsDetails page live link](https://www.virtualcollege.pk/TutorDetails/1105/Sohail%20Anjum)

Here is code for `tutorDetails.jsx` component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { Link,useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from "../_actions/tutorActions";
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';



const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    display: 'flex',
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  card: {
    padding:10,
    marginTop:10,
    display: 'flex',
    flex:1,
  },
  cardAction: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: 'initial'
  },
  cardMedia: {
    width: 160,
  },
});

export default function TutorDetails(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
  
let {tutorId}=useParams(); // get tutorId from url parameter
 
 
  let {fullName}=useParams();// get fullname from parameter
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();
 const tutor = useSelector(state=>state.tutor.list)
  useEffect(() => {
    //call the action creator with dispatch
    //  and wait until the promise resolves
    actions
      .fetchById(tutorId)(dispatch)
       setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>{loading === true ? <span>Loading ! Please waite...</span>:<div>
    <Card className={classes.card} variant="outlined">
      
    <CardContent>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {tutor[0].fullName} <br/> 
   

      </Typography>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {tutor[0].Qualification} 
      </Typography>
      <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
       category: {tutor[0].category}
      

      </Typography>
      
     
      <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
         experience:{tutor[0].experience}<br/>
        subject: {tutor[0].subject}<br/>
        Mobile: 0343-3969030<br/>
        email: virtualcollegepk01@gmail.com<br/>
        
       city: {tutor[0].city}<br/>
       
        </Typography>
        
 
             
    </CardContent>
      </Card>
      </div>}
      
      </div>
      
  );
  
}
```

Here is the link of url in `tutors.jsx` component.

```
    <Link to={`/TutorDetails/${record.tutorId}/${record.fullName}`}
> {record.fullName}</Link>
```

Here is the router link in `App.js`

```
    <Route path="/TutorDetails/:tutorId/:fullName" component={TutorDetails} />
```

the `App.js` component is as below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { history } from '../_helpers';
import { alertActions } from '../_actions/alert.actions';
import { PrivateRoute} from '../_components/PrivateRoute';
import {TeacherCourses} from '../_components/TeacherCourses';
import TutorDetails from '../_components/TutorDetails';
import Tutors from '../_components/Tutors';
import { HomePage } from '../HomePage';
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline'
import theme from '../theme'
import  { ToastProvider} from "react-toast-notifications";
import NewNavbar from "../_components/Header/NewNavbar";
import Footer from "../_components/Header/Footer";
import {carousel} from "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";

function App() {
 
    const alert = useSelector(state => state.alert);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        history.listen((location, action) => {
            // clear alert on location change
            dispatch(alertActions.clear());
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <ToastProvider autoDismiss={true}>
       <Container maxWidth="lg">
                    {alert.message &&
                        <div className={`alert ${alert.type}`}>{alert.message}</div>
                    }
                     
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <div>
                        <NewNavbar/>
                        <Switch>
                
                            <Route path="/TutorDetails/:tutorId/:fullName" component= {TutorDetails} />
                          

                            <Route path="/Tutors" component= {Tutors} />
                          
                            
                            <Route path="/MyCourses/:tutorId/" component= {MyCourses} />
                   
                            <Route path="/Enroll/:courseId/:courseTitle" component={Enroll} />
                            <Route  path="/" component={HomePage} />
                                      
                            <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                        </Switch>
                       <Footer/>
                        </div>
                    </Router>
                   
                    </Container>
        </ToastProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export {App} ;
```

Comment: What URL is being copy/pasted? Can you explain in better/clearer detail what the issue is other than "it's not working"? May we see how your routes are configured? You should provide enough code and context anyone should be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: hi @DrewReese ,i have updated question and added tutors llive ink . i want to copy the url of `tutorsDetails.jsx` page on new browser tab.

Comment: Right, that much I gathered. What is the URL being used that isn't working in a new tab, and how does your app handle routing? Without seeing the code that handles the URL and routing it's nearly impossible to provide any help. If we can't see the code we can't know what it is doing.

Comment: hi @DrewReese i am ready to share code .the page(component) i want to display is `tutorDetails.jsx` whose code is given in question .moreover the link i want to open in new tab is given in `live link`  `https://www.virtualcollege.pk/TutorDetails/1105/Sohail%20Anjum` here `1105` is tutorId and `sohail Anjum` is fullName .moreover the see the question and i am ready to share the code you need to provide help.very thanks for helping me.

Comment: Hello again. Can you include the component code with your `Router`? If you have more than 1 router can you include all code? If possible to also share a link to a repo? I suspect you've more than 1 router and things just happen to work when you navigate from *within* your app, but things fail when externally navigating. I see the detail component appears to get `tutorId` match param from props, but get the `fullName` match param from the router context via the hook.

Comment: very thanks @DrewReese for interest in my problem .I have updated the question and added all relevent code .I hope you will find the solution. I have also corrected `let {tutorId}=useParams();` line to make both parameters similar. tell if you need more code details.

Comment: I wonder if it is an issue with your webserver, IDK. I was also unable to navigate to your `path="/MyCourses/:tutorId/"` page using a known tutor id, i.e. "https://www.virtualcollege.pk/MyCourses/105/" for "Areesha" also doesn't load. Nor does "https://www.virtualcollege.pk/Enroll/30/Biology,%201st%20Year,%20Part%201". I thought maybe the spaces interfered, but they appear to be correctly encoded URIs. I'm a bit stumped ATM.